# vimrc nnoremap no effect after startup with utf-8. vimrc reload fixes

Tags: vim

I have set the following at the beginning of my _vimrc on Windows 8

```
scriptencoding utf-8
set encoding=utf-8
```

Further down the file are the following mappings

```
nnoremap § ~
nnoremap ö :
```

My problem is that the mappings are having no effect after startup of gvim. If I reload the file by opening it and forcing a write such that my

```
:au! BufWritePost $MYVIMRC source $MYVIMRC
```

kicks in, the mappings work. They also work if I manually enter the commands while running gvim.

Running `set fileencoding` reports `fileencoding=utf-8` for my _vimrc.

The version of vim I'm using is 7.4.094/2.7/3.3/2.0.0 from https://bitbucket.org/Haroogan/vim-for-windows.

The mappings work in MacVim on my Mac without modification. Any ideas?

#### Update 1

The output of `:nmap` is displayed as

```
n  §           * ~
n  <f6>        * :
```

Using `redir` to capture the output of `:nmap` and pasting it into a new utf-8 buffer, the `§` is displayed as a greyed out `<a7>`. When copy pasting this back here, the `§` is once again a `§`.

#### Update 2

I installed `gvim74.exe` from vim.org and used the same _vimrc. Nothing changes. My other keymappings work as usual by not `ö` or `§`. I've tried both `gvim.exe` and `vim.exe`, both the official version 7.4 from vim.org and version 7.4.094/2.7/3.3/2.0.0 from https://bitbucket.org/Haroogan/vim-for-windows.

#### Update 3

If I remove the encoding settings

```
scriptencoding utf-8
set encoding=utf-8
```

from my _vimrc, the keybindings work as expected.

Comment: That's strange, you're avoiding all the usual pitfalls. What's the output of `:nmap` before and after re-sourcing? Does the `{lhs}` differ in any way?!

Comment: @Ingo It seems the left hand side indeed does differ. Output added as update to question. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the above problem by simply changing the order of the encoding settings to

```
set encoding=utf-8
scriptencoding utf-8
```

Another solution was to wrap the keymappings with calls to scriptencoding, like this

```
scriptencoding
nnoremap § ~
nnoremap ö :
scriptencoding utf-8
```

I am assuming this changes how text is converted to utf-8, but I'm no vim expert. Please enlighten me exactly why this works! xD